# How do I mount an Ext4 File System with an alternate SuperBlock?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, ext4

I know how to get back a working file-system(FS), the usual way, by running

> e2fsck -b alt_SB_no /dev/sdX

which will fix my FS.

I have an *ext4* image-file that is corrupt - **I want to patch in just the Super Block**. I want to mount it via *loop* using an alternate super-block number. **I DO NOT want to alter the image beyond a SuperBlock**.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `sb=` mount option? ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext2.5.html))

> `sb=n`      Instead of block 1, use block n as superblock. This could be
>                 useful when the filesystem has been damaged.

i.e.

```
mount -oloop,sb=123456 imagefile /mount/point
```